# Changing a source file to compile Main() method in a project, in VS c# console application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, console

I have  a sample c# console project in which I have 2 program files:

1. Program.cs
2. Program02.cs

In *Program.cs* I have the usual main method that is the entry point of the project:

```
public static void main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("hello world from Program.cs");
}
```

But I would like to make the execution of the program from the *Program02.cs* file so I added in the file the method.

```
public static void main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("hello world from Program02.cs");
}
```

Clearly it doesn’t work, the entry point/execution of the project starts at *Program.cs*, how can I switch the main execution method to the *Program02.cs* file?

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right-click on the project in Solution Explorer, and locate:

1. Common Properties
2. General
3. Application
4. Startup Object and set it to the preferred class that contains your `Main()` method

**!!!** You declared your `Main()` method like this: `main()`, which is not correct. It must be `Main()`. C# is a case-sensitive language.

Check this:
[image]

Comment: I don't get those options at->Startup Object, check my screen clipping.

Comment: @Luther I said Rick-Click on project **test_delegates_01** not on `Solution 'test_delegates_01'`. Solution Explorer is the frame where your Projects are situated.

Comment: I did as you said but still it's not working, it gives me just one selction: test_delegates_01.program

Comment: check my clipping I'm using VS2010

Comment: The problem is `public static void main(string[] args)`. It MUST be `Main()` not `main()` because everything is case-sensitive.

Comment: OMG, haven't noticed it, Shame on me! sometimes I forget I'm not in Java world.